# What kind of XP bonus can i get in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

So I saw that I'm getting a XP bonus on the mission select screen:

[image: Mission Select]

I guess the XP bonus is from having Unknown selected, but are there other kinds of XP bonuses that I can get in multiplayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There sure are!

XP is just the sum total of every players score, so the more you (as a team) score, the more XP you'll receive!

I'm going to [quote myself here:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/54004/336)

> #### Individual Achievements
>
> These show up on the end of match results screen, and are worth
> varying amounts of score. Every medal has differing values of Bronze,
> Silver and Gold, and the point values scale linearly with weapon kill
> medals, and geometrically with everything else. This means that
> getting 25 kills with a pistol and 50 kills with an assault rifle nets
> the exact same point bonus as getting 75 kills with an assault rifle,
> but getting 10 headshots and 1 grab is worth less than getting 20
> headshots.
>
> #### Team  Achievements
>
> Some medals are awarded team wide. Mission completion and extraction
> bonuses, for instance, as well as going a certain number of waves
> without losing a squadmate. Like the individual achievements, these
> come in Bronze, Silver, and Gold.
>
> To get your score, the game simply adds all these up.
>
> (A more complete listing is available [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer#Awards).)

Answer (score 2):

You also get a 5% bonus to XP for all matches that you complete while your galactic readiness is maxed out at 100%.